# Why is the PHP version wrong in Symfony Book project?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to follow the Symfony book project from here: https://symfony.com/doc/6.2/the-fast-track/de/2-project.html

But when I run this command:

```
symfony new --version=6.2-1 --book guestbook
```

I got this error:

```
[KO] PHP installed; version 7.2.34 found but we need version 7.2.5+ (/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.34/bin/php)
```

I am using MAMP Pro and have added the path to .zshrc.
34 should be 5+, or not?

I thought Symfony 6.2 needs at leads PHP 8.1

Another error is this:

```
[KO] PHP extension "redis" not found, optional - needed only for chapter 31
```

But I am running Redis in MAMP Pro. On the phpinfo() output page it alsi shows me redis.

What is wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: It is a common question.  You probably have multiple versions of PHP installed and it is not always obvious which version the Symfony CLI is using.  `symfony local:php:list` and `symfony local:php:refresh` will often fix the problem.  And no need to use a version number when you just want to install the latest version of the framework.  Especially the patch version.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used the commands. But still the same error.
Do I have to use exactly PHP 7.2.5?
I have this Versions in MAMP:
7.2.34, 7.4.21, 8.0.8, 8.1.0
I downloaded 7.2.5. But somehow it is not recognised my MAMP.

Comment: You need php 8.1 or later.  If you really have 8.1 installed then the local:php:list command should show it.  Make sure your Symfony CLI version is also up to date.  Should be around 5.4.21 or so.  I'm fortunate enough to not have to use windows so I can't really help much more except maybe try reinstalling MAMP.

Comment: Yes, I am also thinking it need 8.1. I set 8.1 as default now. But I still got this error: PHP installed; version 8.1.0 found but we need version 7.2.5+ (/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.1.0/bin/php)
So, what is correct now?

Comment: If you search for `found but we need version 7.2.5+` you will find a number of hits mostly involving composer.json files that have been incorrectly updated.  I'd suggest deleting anything symfony related and just start over.  Or at least do some research on what other people did with this message.

Comment: yes, you probably cloned version 5.0-1 -> https://github.com/the-fast-track/book-5.0-1  but instead you wanted to clone version 6.2-1 https://github.com/the-fast-track/book-6.2-1

Comment: So far I only installed the symfony CLI. It is 5.4.21, the newest. Then I wanted to install the book project with it: symfony new --version=6.2-1 --book guestbook
When I ececute: symfony book:check-requirements I also got the same error. Now I have cloned the project. That was a good hint.

Comment: I have read several "found but we need version 7.2.5+" posts. What really confuses me is that the book project needs version 8.1 but it complaints it needs version 7.2.5+. In my .zshrc I set:
`export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.1.0/bin:$PATH`
Where does it come from?